# Prevent boost::asio::io_context from returning when there is no more work to do

Tags: c++, boost-asio

`boost::asio::io_context::run()` does return when no work is pending. I would like to avoid this behavior, so that `run()` does wait indefinitely for new works, with the possibility to stop it from another thread.

This could be done, I guess, by starting an infinitely long timer in the `io_context`, and by calling `cancel()` on that timer when we want `run()` to return.

Is this a proper approach and is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [executor_work_guard](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/executor_work_guard.html).
In ctor it takes executor from io_context instance and call `on_work_started` on this executor what means that `io_context::run` doesn't end when there is no work to do [see reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__executor_type/on_work_started.html).

> This ensures that the io_context's run() and run_one() functions do
>   not exit while the work is underway.

So the simple code looks like

```
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  boost::asio::executor_work_guard<decltype(io.get_executor())> work{io.get_executor()};

  io.run(); // [1]
  cout << "you will never see this line" << endl;
```

code hangs in [1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) line. `io_context::run` might end when `work` destructor was called.

On older boost or asio versions, the equivalent class is [io_service::work](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html)

Comment: or by a bit more readable `auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io);`