# About using asio::work or can't keep io_context.run from exiting

Tags: c++, linux, tcp, asio

I am working on an asynchronous tcp client, and I have inquired about a lot of information about `io_context.run`. In order to keep him from exiting, I use `asio::work` to maintain `io_context.run()`

But my code doesn't work, it still closes the program when it finishes executing

1. application (It is feasible when I write worker and thread in main)
   Like the part commented below

```
#include "socket_tcp_client/client.h"

using namespace kenyence_tcp;


int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;



    //////It is feasible when I write worker and thread in main
    //////Like the part commented below

    // boost::asio::io_context::work worker(io_context);
    // std::thread t([&io_context]()
    //     {
    //         while (true)
    //         {
    //             io_context.run();
    //         }
    //     });
    auto kenyence_ptr = std::make_shared<kenyence_client>(io_context);  

    // kenyence_ptr->initialize("127.0.0.1", 15001);

    std::cout << "main thread waitting for 1 second\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); 

    
    kenyence_ptr->connect("127.0.0.1", 15001);
    
    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0x78); 
    
    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0xAC); 
    
    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0xDD); 
    
    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0xBB); 
    
    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0xCC); 

    kenyence_ptr->setNextbyte(0xFF); 
    
    // io_context.stop();
    // t.join();

    std::cout << "flinish\n";
    // kenyence_ptr->stopTcpCommuncation();

    return 0;
}
```

2. client.cpp
   The Lib used here is normal, except that I moved the worker and thread to the class, and the program will be closed after execution

```
#include "socket_tcp_client/client.h"


namespace kenyence_tcp
{

    kenyence_client::kenyence_client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
            : ioContext_{io_context}, 
            connector_{std::make_shared<Connector>(io_context)},
            isRunning_{false}, 
            isSessionOK_{false},
            isStop_{false},
            worker_{io_context}
    {
        
    }

    kenyence_client::~kenyence_client() 
    {
        std::cout << "Is in distructer\n";
        if (workingThread_.joinable()) 
        {
            workingThread_.join();
        }
        
        stopTcpCommuncation();
    }

    int kenyence_client::connect(const std::string &ipStr, int port)
    {
        int rtn = 0;
        do
        {
            rtn = kenyence_client::initialize(ipStr , port);
            std::cout << "TCPIP Initialize Finish\n";

            if(rtn == 0)
            {
                openIoContextThread();
                std::cout << "Already Create io_context Thread\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000000));
                rtn = 1;
            }

            if(rtn == 1)
            {
                connect2Server();
                std::cout << "Connect to Server ........\n";
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000000));
                rtn = 2;
            }

            if(rtn == 2)
            {
                startWriteThread();
                std::cout << "Already open Write Thread\n";
            }


        }while(false);

        return rtn;
    }

    void kenyence_client::openIoContextThread()
    {   
        ioContextThread_ = std::thread([this](){
                IoContextThreadBody();
            });
    }

    void kenyence_client::IoContextThreadBody()
    {
        while(true)
        {   
            try
            {
                ioContext_.run();
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    int kenyence_client::initialize(const std::string &ipStr, int port) 
    {
        boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::make_address(ipStr);
        endpoint_ = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(address, port);
        return 0;
    }

    void kenyence_client::connect2Server() 
    {
        std::cout << "In <coneect2Server>\n";
        connector_->start(ioContext_, endpoint_, [self = shared_from_this()](std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket)
        {
            self->session_ = std::make_shared<Session>(self->ioContext_, std::move(*socket));
            self->isSessionOK_ = true; //等到建立了Session才能通訊
            if(self->session_)
                std::cout << "Already create seesion_\n";
            self->session_->start(std::bind(&kenyence_client::onReceiveFrame, self, std::placeholders::_1),
                                  [self](){  
                                      self->isSessionOK_ = false;
                                      self->session_->stop([self](){
                                          if (self->isRunning_) {
                                              //after stop, trigger another run, so that it will try to reconnect
                                              self->connect2Server();
                                              
                                          }
                                      });
                                  });
        });
    }

    void kenyence_client::stop() 
    {
        session_->stop([this](){
            std::cout << "disconnected" << std::endl;
            isSessionOK_ = false;
            isRunning_ = false;
        });
    }

    void kenyence_client::onReceiveFrame(const Frame &frame) 
    {       
        auto frameSize = frame.parseFrameSize(0x01);
        frame.print(frameSize, std::cout);
    }


    void kenyence_client::startWriteThread()
    {
        if (!isRunning_) 
        {
            isRunning_ = true;
            workingThread_ = std::thread([this]()
            {   
                workingThreadBody();
            });
        }
    }

    void kenyence_client::workingThreadBody()
    {
        while (isRunning_) 
        {
            if (isSessionOK_) 
            {
                writeToServer();
            } 
        }
    }

    void kenyence_client::writeToServer() 
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            if(needSend_)
            {
                session_->write(preSendBuffer_.data(), preSendBuffer_.size());
                needSend_ = false;
                std::cout << "In <writeToServer> Data is : " << std::hex<<(uint16_t)preSendBuffer_[0] <<std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            }
        }
    }
    void kenyence_client::setNextbyte(unsigned char context)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            this->preSendBuffer_[0] = context;
            needSend_ = true;
            std::cout << "In <setNextbyte> Data is : " << std::hex<<(uint16_t)preSendBuffer_[0] <<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(500000));
    }

    void kenyence_client::stopTcpCommuncation()
    {
        isStop_ = true;
        if(ioContextThread_.joinable())
        {
            std::cout << "Closing client communication\n";
            ioContext_.stop();
            ioContextThread_.join();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "wrong\n";
        }
    }


}
```

3. client.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "frame.h"
#include "session.h"
#include "connector.h"



namespace kenyence_tcp
{
    class kenyence_client : public std::enable_shared_from_this<kenyence_client>
    {
        public:
            kenyence_client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context);
            ~kenyence_client();

            int connect(const std::string &ipStr, int port);
            void stop();
            void setNextbyte(unsigned char context);
            void stopTcpCommuncation();

            int initialize(const std::string &ipStr, int port);
            void connect2Server();
            void openIoContextThread();
            void startWriteThread();

        private:
            boost::asio::io_context &ioContext_;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint_;
            std::shared_ptr<Connector> connector_;
            std::shared_ptr<Session> session_;

            std::thread workingThread_ , ioContextThread_;
            boost::asio::io_context::work worker_;
            bool isRunning_, isSessionOK_ ,isStop_ ;

            std::mutex mutex_;
            unsigned char nextByte_;
            bool needSend_;
            std::array<uint8_t , 1> preSendBuffer_;
            
            void writeToServer();

            void IoContextThreadBody();
            void workingThreadBody();
            void onReceiveFrame(const Frame &frame);
    };
}
```

Flinish is finally printed like the picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxDrc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaOwD.png)

I have tried various methods and still can't solve the problem. I hope that when no messages are sent or received, the connection can also be maintained without closing the program

Comment: It looks like you ended the program with ctrl-c? `finished` will be printed before the end of your program, the destructor of `kenyence_client` will be called after your print

Comment: The same happens when I'm not using crtl+c, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Your program ends or prints `finished` and keeps running?

Comment: The purpose of outputting finsih is to see if it is because it exits after executing the functions in main. What I hope is that the program keeps running. If there is no transmission or reception, it will also keep waiting without exiting.

Comment: 2 things I've noticed. 1) You use `io_context::work` which is deprecated. Use `executor_work_guard` instead (relative question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751302/prevent-boostasioio-context-from-returning-when-there-is-no-more-work-to-do). And 2) you call `ioContext.run()` in a loop. Don't do that, simply call it once and the work guard will keep it busy

Comment: I have changed it to the executor_work_guard you mentioned, and deleted the while loop, but the problem still exists